# Android TextView over ImageView positioning

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, textview

I'm trying to position a textview over an imageview used as a background image. My problem is that Android calculates the position based on the length of the text of the textview, so when I position it with a certain text, a longer text pushes it out of position again. This is what I want to achieve. The big black thing is a single picture I'd rather not cut up just so I can position these two textviews (in red). My problem is that the textviews arent at any "android" position i.e. center/left/right of anything.

[image]

Comment: Post your code here what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your TextViews in vertical LinearLayout.
To move this LinearLayout in the middle (left or right of the middle) use horizontal LinearLayout with empty view and android:layout_weight attribute.
For example:

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"

&lt;ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:src="@drawable/your_image" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

&lt;LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
&lt;View
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="0dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1.2"/>
&lt;LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
&lt;TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:text="Short text"/>
&lt;TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:text="Looooooooooooooooooooooong text"/>
        &lt;/LinearLayout&gt;
    &lt;/LinearLayout&gt;
&lt;/RelativeLayout&gt;
```